# The open set in the subspace of a metric space.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I'm learning Metric Space (*Mathematical Analysis* by Zorich) and here is my problem:

$(X_1,d_1)$ is a subspace of the metric space $(X,d)$, an openset $G_1$ of $X_1$ means:
$\forall x \in G_1,\exists B_1(x;r)=\{y\in X_1|d_1(x,y)<r\}\subset G_1$.

It's obvious that $B_1(x;r)=X_1 \cap B(x;r)$

But can every open set $G_1$ of $X_1$ be expressed as $G_1=X_1\cap G$ where $G$ is a open set of $X$? And how to prove it? (How to find the set $G$?)

Comment: That is literally the definition of what it means to be open in the subspace topology.

Comment: Thank you! but I wanna know in Zorich's analysis G_1open means forall x in G_1, exists a B(x;r) \subset G_1, why this kind of defition is same as above?

Comment: @LEY Because $G_1$ is open, by definition of open set, every point $x$ in $G_1$ has a basic which is $B(x, r)$ contained in $G_1$

Comment: What is $d_1$? ${}{}$

Comment: @Arctic Char, $d_1$ is the metric on $X_1, d_1=d|_{X_1}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $G_1$ be open in $X_1$. Then for each $x\in G_1$, there is $r>0$ depending on $x$ so that

$$ B_1(x, r) = \{ y\in X_1: d(y, x) <r\} \subset G_1.$$

Let $G = \cup_{x\in G_1} B(x, r) \subset X$. Then $G$ is open in $X$ and $X_1\cap G = G_1$:

- $\supset$ is obvious.
- Let $y\in X_1\cap G$. Since $y\in G$, there is $x\in G_1 $ so that $y\in B(x, r)$. Thus $d(y, x)<r$. But since $y\in X_1$ we have $y\in B_1(x, r)$ and so $y\in G_1$.